# How to establish Observer and Observable both on a client class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have a `Class A` which notify to `Class B` once any change made to `A`, and the class `B` as well notifies to `A` and vice versa.

How to implement such design? Any sample will work.

Comment: The answer's in your title. There's nothing special here, just use the Observer pattern. Both ways.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is completely interchangeable from Observer to Subject (or vice versa), after all they are simply objects notifying other objects. Simply do,

```
interface ISubject 
{ 
    void notifyObservers(); 
}

interface IObserver 
{ 
    void notify(); 
}

class A : ISubject, IObserver
{
    public void notifyObservers()
    {
        // Notify B that I've change!
    }

    public void notify()
    {
        // B has changed, do something!
    }
}

class B : ISubject, IObserver
{
    public void notifyObservers()
    {
        // Notify A that I've change!
    }

    public void notify()
    {
        // A has changed, do something!
    }
}
```